# TaskCompletionSource in async function

Tags: c#, .net

I have such a function:

```
public async Task<bool> DoSomething()
{
   var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

   // Here is the problem. I need to keep this line because I wait on something asynchronously, but the function must return bool and I can't just return tcs.Task
   while(something)
      await Task.Delay(100);

   someobject.somevent += () => {
      // do some sht
      tcs.SetResult(true);
   }

   // it doesn't work
   return tcs.Task;
}
```

It's just a fake code but I have real situation where I need this. I want to keep DoSomething asynchronous but I also want to keep Task.Delay/Sleep in it. How do I do this in not-async function returning just Task?

UPDATE:

THIS WORKS:

```
class Program
    {
        static TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();


        static Task<bool> Test()
        {
           // tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting...");
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                Console.WriteLine("Setting result");
                if(tcs.TrySetResult(true))
                    Console.WriteLine("Result has been set");


            });

            return tcs.Task;
        }

        static async Task Test2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting awaiting");
            var result = await Test();
            Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            Test2();

            Console.ReadKey(false);

        }
    }
```

and this doesn't

```
static async Task<bool> Test()
{
   // tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting...");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Console.WriteLine("Setting result");
        if(tcs.TrySetResult(true))
            Console.WriteLine("Result has been set");


    });


    return await tcs.Task;
}
```

what's worse, I have tested it in my windows forms app and awaiting tcs.Task caused weird crash coming from System.Threading....dll

Comment: What do you mean by *"how do I do this in not-async function?"* If you're using `Task.Delay`, the method has to be async and return a `Task` or `Task<T>`. Moreso, if you're already using `await`, you don't need the `TaskCompletionSource` at all.

Comment: `return await tcs.Task;`

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov yes, it is async but things got complicated after I have put TaskCompletionSource there because it can't be async anymore and I have to find other way for waiting

Comment: If it can't be async, you won't be able to asynchronously wait anyway. Not sure I understand where you're going. Sounds bit a like the XY problem.

Comment: I think @spender understood my problem. I just wanted to know how to use TaskCompletionSource in async followed function.

Comment: The second does not work because Task.Factory.StartNew is not supposed to be used in async programing. The second Test() method might return even before the inner is executed.

Answer (score 19):

If I understand correctly (it's tricky because your question isn't that easy to follow) you can restate things as follows:

```
public async Task<bool> DoSomething()
{
   var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
   someobject.somevent += () => {
      // do some sht
      tcs.SetResult(true);
   }

   return await tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will try it

Comment: it doesn't work, causes the app to wait forever, no matter where I call SetResult. It works only in functions without async keyword.

Comment: @Konrad That wouldn't have anything to do with the code shown.  If the app is waiting forever then the class isn't firing the event, or you've got a deadlock from performing a synchronous wait from a synchronization context that has continuations necessary to complete the task being waited on.  In either case, it's not the method shown here with the problem.

Comment: Thanks for this! I was missing the await in the return and was confused as to why Visual Studio wasn't allowing me to just `return tcs.Task`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, just replaced `someobject.somevent += () =>` with `Task.Run(async () => ... )` (Needed to be an async action for me because I wanted to use the results of a task to set or cancel this task)

Answer (score 13):

The whole thing will come out a lot more elegantly if you separate out the logic of turning the event firing into a `Task` into its own method.

```
public static Task<bool> WhenSomeEvent(this SomeObject someobject)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    Action handler = null;
    handler = () =>
    {
        tcs.SetResult(true);
        someobject.SomeEvent -= handler;
    };
    someobject.SomeEvent += handler;
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

This allows you to write the business logic separately, without mixing in all of the logic of translating the event into a `Task`:

```
public async Task<bool> DoSomething()
{
    while(something)
        await Task.Delay(100);

    return await someobject.WhenSomeEvent();
}
```